# How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$ have, where $a$ is a zero of $f(x)$ in some extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $\mathbb{Z}_2=F$. Let $f(x)=x^3+x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. Suppose $a$ is a zero of $f(x)$ in some extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. How many elements does $F(a)$ have and express each member of $F(a)$ in terms of $a$.

My Try:

Some info I understand:

$f(x)$ has degree $3$ and doesn't have a root in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so we conclude that because the degree is low, there are $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Since $f(x)$ is irreducible I know that $\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / \langle f(x)\rangle $ is a field(I'm not sure if this information is relevant to the question or not.)

$a$ is a root so $f(a)=0$ in some extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Can someone help push me in the right direction?

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, you're right. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Hint: every extension of degree $n$ of $\Bbb{F}_p$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field consists of all polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ of degree at most $2$ evaluated at $a$.

This is because the field $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle$ is "produced" by taking all polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and reduce them modulo the polynomial $f(x)$.

Comment: No problem. For the next time: it is usually better to answer homework-related questions with a hint (or a series of hints, if needed) at first, and complete it only after the OP understands it (or if s/he can't get to it in a reasonable amount of time).

Comment: Thanks. This is my first month taking this duty seriously, I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Heh, sometimes the community can be a bit harsh, but posting MSE should be first and foremost (math-related) fun! :)

Comment: @DanielEscudero: Why are we considering $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x \rangle$?

Comment: It was a typo, I'm sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: @DanielEscudero: No problem. I just wanted to make sure I was understanding. So, I think that the polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ of degree at most $2$ evaluated at $a$ (for which $a$ is a zero) are $0,a,a^2, a+a^2$? But why are we considering polynomials of degree $2$ and not of degree $3$?

Comment: @NathanC. (There are more degree two polynomials) Each time you have a polynomial of degree $3$, you can apply long division to divide it by $f(x)$ and obtain a reidue (i.e., you can reduce it modulo $f$).

Comment: @NathanC. For example, if you consider the degree $3$ polynomial $x^3+x^2+x+1$, it can be realized as $1\cdot f(x)+x^2$ so in the quotient this polinomial is just $x^2$.

Comment: @DanielEscudero: Ah, ok, I see what you mean. I think I'm just a little confused about why $a$ being a zero of $f(x)$ in an extension field is relevant at all?

Comment: @NathanC. It's relevant, of course. It technically defines the way $a$ is going to be "operated" in the extension field. Notice that if $b$ is the root of any other polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $3$, then the extension by $b$ contains "the same" elements than the extension with $a$ but they're operated differently. This is irrelevant for counting purposes.

Comment: @DanielEscudero: Okay. I think I've got it:

Comment: @DanielEscudero:

$\mathbb{Z}_2/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is a field and more notably is an extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Taking mod $2$ of all possible polynomials of degree $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $f(a)=0$ in our extension field will give us the following polynomials:

$0,1,a,a^2,a+a^2,a+1,a^2+1,a^2+a+1$

Does this sound correct?

Comment: @NathanC. At first, the set $\mathbb{Z}_2 / \langle f(x) \rangle$ has no sense since the ideal $ \langle f(x) \rangle$ is not a subset of the ring (field) $\mathbb{Z}_2$. The field you are referring to is $\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / \langle f(x) \rangle$. Yes, this field can be realized as an extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_2$; No, we don't take mod $2$,  we take mod $f(x)$, the sentence should be: "Taking mod $f(x)$ to all possible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ leads to the following polynomials..." and yes, your list is right.

Comment: @DanielEscudero: I apologize. Yes, of course I meant $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle$. I always keep forgetting to write the $[x]$ part of it... Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @NathanC. You're welcome, and be careful with the use of the notation, I'm sure you wrote that unintentionally but in any case, it's important to be aware of that.